# Java HashMap Shift Value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have hash map like this below.And i want to shift values up when upper values are null.

```
HashMap 
Key1 Val1
Key2 
Key3 
Key4 Val4
Key5 
Key6 Val6
```

Become like this

```
HashMap 
Key1 Val1
Key2 Val4
Key3 Val6
Key4 
Key5 
Key6
```

And then delete null value key like this.

```
HashMap 
Key1 Val1
Key2 Val4
Key3 Val6
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense because a `HashMap` hasn't got a defined ordering, so there is no "Key2" that's the second key. You can easily remove keys with null values, though: `map.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this meaningfully with a `HashMap` because it doesn't have a defined ordering, so there is no "second key" - `Key2` - to move `Val4` up to.

But you can do it if you have an ordered `Map`, such as a `TreeMap` (this code works generally on any mutable `Map`; but it only gives predictable results on a map with defined iteration order):

```
Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<?, V>> entryIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
// Find non-null values, set the next entry's value to that.
for (String val : map.values()) {
  if (val != null) {
    entryIterator.next().setValue(val);
  }
}

// Remove the rest of the entries, because we have no non-null
// values to assign to them.
while (entryIterator.hasNext()) {
  entryIterator.next();
  entryIterator.remove();
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/bZNeUd)